# Finding the Measure of Angle LSM in a Right-Angled Triangle with an Inscribed Circle

Tags: triangles, angle, bisection

In a right-angled triangle KLM with a right angle at the vertex K, S is the center of the circle inscribed in it. The size of the LSM angle is:

The answer is 135º but I don't where to start, or how to do this question.

Comment: HINT. $LS$ and $MS$ are angle bisectors.

Answer (score 1):

A line drawn from a vertex to the center of an incircle bisects the angle at that vertex, and the internal angles of a triangle must add up to 180˚. In the diagram below,
\begin{align*}
\,2\alpha+2\beta=90˚\\
\implies\alpha + \beta=45˚\\
\implies \gamma=180˚-45˚=135˚
\end{align*}
[image]